# How do I find out the machine name of a view in hook_preprocess_views_view_field?

Tags: views, theming, 8, hooks

In Drupal 8, I am trying to use `hook_preprocess_views_view_fields` to process certain fields of certain views. I know how to test for the field name via `$variables['field']->field`, but I can't find any similar way to test for the view's machine name. Is there a similar way to do it for the view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The view itself is in the `$variables` array for all of the views hooks.

```
/** @var \Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view */
$view = $variables['view'];
$view->id();
```

should give you what you are looking for.